# RadListView no funciona

Tags: angular, nativescript

Tengo esta parte de html en mi código y no se que estoy haciendo mal.

```
<GridLayout rows="auto,*,*"  row="0">                          
    <Label text="TIENES SELECCIONADO: " class="sel" row="0"></Label> 
    <WrapLayout class="deportes_sel" orientation="horizontal" row="1" height="100">
        <ListView [items]="dpt_array" >
            <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
                <GridLayout orientation="horizontal" columns="*, auto">
                    <Label [text]="item" col="0"></Label>
                    <Label text="&#xf014;" class="icon" (tap)="delete(item)" col="1"></Label>
                </GridLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </ListView>
    </WrapLayout>
    <GridLayout rows="*" class="deportes_sel" orientation="horizontal" row="2">
        <RadListView [items]="dpt_array" selectionBehavior="Press" multipleSelection="true">
            <!-- << angular-listview-item-selection-multiple -->
                <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                    <StackLayout class="listItemStackLayout">
                        <Label class="nameLabel" [text]="item"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ng-template>
                <ListViewLinearLayout tkListViewLayout itemHeight="50" scrollDirection="Vertical"></ListViewLinearLayout>
        </RadListView>
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Y en concreto, qué es lo que necesitas?

Comment: crear una lista de deportes, como vi que tenía para seleccionar press o longpress, pensé que me vendría bien, solo con pulsar sobre el deporte para seleccionarlo. Y asi añadirlo a la base de datos del usuario.